# How to retrive the whole data from a specific child path and assign them in that Model class as shown below of Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Model class

```
public class Restaurant {
    private List<CustomerDetails> customer_details;
    private List<Recipes> recipes;
    private Details details;
    private String shop_name;

    public Restaurant() {
    }

    public List<CustomerDetails> getCustomer_details() {
        return customer_details;
    }

    public void setCustomer_details(List<CustomerDetails> customer_details) {
        this.customer_details = customer_details;
    }

    public List<Recipes> getRecipes() {
        return recipes;
    }

    public void setRecipes(List<Recipes> recipes) {
        this.recipes = recipes;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getShop_name() {
        return shop_name;
    }

    public void setShop_name(String shop_name) {
        this.shop_name = shop_name;
    }
}
```

I want to read the whole data for my android app, those are the child of **restaurant**
There have multiple lists and objects. However, I've created all the Model class for it.

So how should I read it? I can read any list from this Firebase Realtime database. But I can cant read the whole data from a specific path..

Please Help!!!

```
mDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("restautant");
mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {......
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to read the whole data"?

Comment: I want to assign the whole data in my model class. so that I can use later.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your model classes.

Comment: Yes I have added the model class Please help

Comment: Please do NOT include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Kindly help me out.

Comment: If you try to get the data, not as a model, rather as a single property, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the list of data. But how to store the whole data sets in the MODEL class? Again I'm asking the same.